# Angular 2 ERROR Error: No provider for myService! Dependency Injection issue

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular2-services

In this Angular 2 sample project I'm working on (from Visual Studio 2015) I added a provider for a custom service to a child component, but when I run the project I get the error message in Google debugger that there is no provider for myService in the child component and that particular component wont render.  But if declare the provider for myService at the root component level, the project runs without this error message and the child component(s) will render.  Here is the code in the child component that isn't rendering but should (called home.component.ts) -- the 2 child components are contained in a ul tab arrangement in the parent component.  The exercise is to not render the 2nd child component but yes render the first child component (home.component.ts)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { UserPreferencesService } from '../employee/userPreferences.service';

@Component({
    //--note no selector in this child component and this div is not rendering but will render if I declare the provider at the root level

    template: `<h1>This is the home page</h1>
        <div>
            Colour Preference :
            <input type='text' [(ngModel)]='colour' [style.background]='colour' />
        </div>
    `,
    providers: [UserPreferencesService]
})

export class HomeComponent {
    //--this is the Dependency Injection version of the serive
    constructor(private _userPreferencesService: UserPreferencesService) {

    }

    get colour(): string {
        return this._userPreferencesService.colourPreference;
    }

    set colour(valueX: string) {
        this._userPreferencesService.colourPreference = valueX;
    }

}
```

and here is the (abbreviated) code in the parent component (called app.compoent.ts)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `    
    .....
    <list-employee></list-employee>
    <br /><br />
     Your Text : <input type='text' [(ngModel)]='userText'/>
     <br /><br />
     <simple [simpleInput]='userText'></simple>

     <!--this is the div section that won't render when declaring the provider
     //--in child component (home).  The Employees child component is supposed to error out -->
     <div style="padding:5px">
         <ul class="nav nav-tabs">                        
             <li routerLinkActive="active"> <a [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</a> </li>
             <li routerLinkActive="active"> <a [routerLink]="['employees']">Employees</a> </li>
             <br />
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>
          </ul>
       </div>

     </div> 

     `
})
export class AppComponent {  
    ......
```

and here is the root component (called app.module.ts) which contains the @ngModule directive

```
......
import { EmployeeService } from './employee/employee.service';
import { UserPreferencesService } from './employee/userPreferences.service';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'employees', component: EmployeeListComponent },
    { path: 'employees/:code', component: EmployeeComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
]

@NgModule({
    //imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true }) ]
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes) ],
    declarations: [AppComponent, EmployeeComponent, EmployeeListComponent, EmployeeTitlePipe, EmployeeCountComponent, SimpleComponent, HomeComponent, PageNotFoundComponent ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: [EmployeeService]
    //providers: [EmployeeService, UserPreferencesService] -- when I declare this provider in  the child component I am getting the error message -- if I add UserPreferenceService here in the root then both child components will render and no error message
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Either I am missing something in one of the components.ts or there is some Angular 2 syntax issue -- which I have noticed that in the tutorial I'm following sometimes the author includes/excludes brackets on various lines.  How can I resolve this error -- No provider for myService?

Comment: I noticed that if I register the provider with the 2nd child component then both child components render without the error message.  If I register the provider at the root level, both child components will render.  But if I register the provider with only one child but not the other neither of the child components will render.  That is my problem.  I believe the first child component should render since I registered the provider for it, but not the 2nd child component.  What am I missing?

Comment: I noticed that if I include -- providers: [UserPreferencesService] -- in both of the child components -- home.component.ts and employeeList.component.ts, then the project runs normally (except with two 'singleton' classes of the same thing).  If I exclude the provider for home.component, the project still runs for the employeeList.component, but if exclude the provider in employeeList... and include only in home.component... then I get the error msg.  employeeList.componet contains its own employeeList.component.html file where home.component does not.  Mayb that why not working as advertised.